# Failing to load my script files in wordpress! i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

i have customized my .html as a custom wp theme.
i have these scripts in my header.php:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/diapo.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>

<!--[if !IE]><!--><script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.customized.min.js'></script><!--<![endif]-->

<!-- html5.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I am really new in all these wp customization stuff and i am struggling through dozens of tutorials by great minds out there sharing their knowledge. after a quite long search before posting here, i see that the right way including these files is registering and queuing them inside my functions.php file.

so, my "functions.php" has this:

```
function load_javascript_files() {

//Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'), '1.3', true);
wp_register_script('hoverIntent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_register_script('jquery-mob-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.customized.min.js', array(jquery), true);
wp_register_script('home-page-slideshow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/diapo.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_register_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);


wp_enqueue_script('easing');
wp_enqueue_script('hoverIntent');
wp_enqueue_script('custom-script');

global $is_IE;

if ( $is_IE ) {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mob-custom');
}

if(is_front_page()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('home-page-slideshow');
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files');

?>
```

Any help of understanding what i am doing wrong here is really appreciated

Comment: in your easing script, you append `get_template_directory_uri()` to an absolute URL.

Comment: What does the rendered output (browser source) show? Are *any* of the scripts enqueued, or are *none* of the scripts enqueued?

Answer (score 1):

## Probable Cause

I strongly suspect that you do not call [**`wp_head()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) in your `header.php` file, immediately before the closing HTML `</head>` tag:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

You must call this template tag, in order to fire the `wp_head` action. The `wp_head` action in turn fires the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. So, without having `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in your template, you won't fire `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

## Syntax Errors

You have at least three syntax errors:

1. Concatenated script URL:

   ```
   wp_register_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'), '1.3', true);
   ```

   This:

   ```
   get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js'
   ```

   ...should be this:

   ```
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js'
   ```
2. Array key string:

   ```
   wp_register_script('jquery-mob-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.customized.min.js', array(jquery), true);
   ```

   This:

   ```
   array(jquery)
   ```

   ...should be this:

   ```
   array( 'jquery' )
   ```
3. Incorrect `wp_enqueue_script()` parameter ordering

   ```
   wp_register_script('hoverIntent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js', array('jquery'), true);
   wp_register_script('jquery-mob-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.customized.min.js', array(jquery), true);
   wp_register_script('home-page-slideshow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/diapo.js', array('jquery'), true);
   ```

   In each case, you need to add the `$version` parameter between `$deps` and `$footer`

Comment: about 1 and 2 are indeed totally false but scripts don't work either way. about the 1st probably this confused me: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-wordpress-32-and-sliders-jquery-easing

Comment: about the $version i thought that it is optional. if not, then what should i write for $version? by including 
`<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>` instead of the wp_register and wp_enqueue is not the right way? viewing code source, my scripts do not appear anywhere in the <head>..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, but to be honest, i did not totally comprehend why was this happening: i did not register my scripts, just used wp_enqueue_script(); inside my function and now everything is working fine. Simply deleted the wp_register_script(); as it seems that it messed things up. Thank you, however.